# Angular js with Jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have Angular code:

```
  $scope.updateCategory = function(cat,test) {
        res = angular.element(document.querySelector(
                $(this)
                  .parent()
                  .parent()
                  .find('.custom_cat_name')
                  .val()));
        alert(res);
```

I want to get input value of $(this) of an element .

Can I do this?

Currently it is showing [object Object], which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I strongly advise you to read:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that?

I assume the `custom_cat_name` is a class placed on an input element(that should be binded somewhere on your model).

Simply access the element from the model something like:

```
$scope.model.customCat
```

Instead of using `JQuery`.

Anyway, youre doing something **bad** by using `JQuery` from your controller.